# Website thumbnail is not working with facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On my website I am trying to create a Facebook thumbnail so that when I share a picture I want Facebook to select a specific picture. I have ONE number in each url of my site and according to that number I have an image that should display in that page. Any way I wrote the code below, but for a reason it is not working. I want to keep `href` empty then access it through `document.getElementById('ShareImageID').href` and change its value according the value of the var `ShareImageIdVar`. Any ideas how can I get this to work ?

```
<link rel="image_src" href="" id="ShareImageID"/>
<script>
var ShareImageIdVar = location.href.match(/\d+/);
document.getElementById('ShareImageID').href = "http://www.mysite.com/Images/"+ ShareImageIdVar +".jpg";
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get Facebook to select a photo, you need to specify the `og:image` meta tag in the `head` section.  See http://ogp.me for info on how to set those up properly.  Once you got those setup correctly, then lint the url at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: <meta property="og:title" content="My site" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com" />
Now I have this how can I change the src or the content of the og:image property ?

Comment: You cannot change it dynamically AFTER the page is rendered as the Facebook linter does NOT run javascript.  You will need to ensure your webserver response contains the correct og meta data.

Comment: so if this does not work can I still what I have already ? <link rel="image_src" href="" id="ShareImageID"/>